# How can I use Apple's In-App Purchases (IAPs) in their Sandbox Enviroment?

Tags: in-app-purchase

According to [these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox), we should be able to make IAPs against the Sandbox environment in Xcode.

However, I ([and apparently several others](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720179)) have run into an issue where the environment is always `Xcode` and not `Sandbox`, which causes our IAP verification to fail.

[image: Environment: Xcode]

In TestFlight, our IAPs are running against production, which also causes their verification to fail.

We just need a way to successfully verify IAPs in non-production envioronments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure there's no Storekit configration in your scheme

[image]

Also remember to use development-signed bundle and sandbox account to test.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the StoreKit Config and cleaning the Build Folder did the trick for me